# Crop PDF and save it using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, crop

How to crop PDF image in iFrame? And how to save the cropped image in same format?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using somekind of API provided by the PDF reader embedded in the browser..

Comment: PDFBox will let you rasterize pages easily. I'll post a snippet in a sec.

Comment: Thanks @Thihara. Any other options available in jquery

Comment: Oops -- you wanted javascript. I saw the Java tag. PDFBox will work on the server side, anyway.

Comment: Ya anything both javascript or jquery

Comment: I don't think so. PDF is viewed by a separate program embedded in the browser. If you want the user to be able to crop and image from the pdf I think most new reader have that functionality in themselves. You may also want to look into javascript pdf viewers. If rendering is done there they will have an API to manipulate the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on the server in Java, PDFBox (http://pdfbox.apache.org/) can rasterize images.  A stripped down pattern, without error-checking, quality options, etc, might look sort of like this:

```
File file = new File("filename.pdf");
OutputStream outputStream = // ?
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
List<PDPage> pages = (List<PDPage>) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDPage page = pages.get(0);
// 24 bit image, 100dpi:
BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR, 100);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputStream);
```

Comment: uv.  now, if i could just find a c++ version...